# Equivalent definitions of Sylow p-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

A **Sylow $p$-subgroup** $P$ of $G$ is defined（1） as a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$, i.e $P$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$ such that there does exists a $p$-subgroup $P'$ of $G$ properly containing $P$

But I saw another definition（2） of Sylow $p$-subgroup: $P$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$ such that $[G:P]$ is not divisible by $p$.

I am trying to show the equivalence by First Sylow Theorem, but I got stuck.

My attempt:

Assume (1). Let $|P|=p^k$. By Lagrange, we have $|G|=mp^k$ for some $m$ and $[G:P]=m$.

Suppose $p|[G:P]$, then there exists $1\le k'$ such that $[G:P]=p^{k'}m'$ for some $m'$ with $gcd(p,m')=1$. Therefore $|G|=m'p^{k+k'}$. Since $k+k'>k,$ by first Sylow Theorem,there exists a $p$-subgroup $P'$ with $|P'|=P^{k+1}$

I want to claim $P'$ is a $p$-subgroup properly containing $P$. But I have no idea how to do that, or I may be in a totally wrong way.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**Answer**

Suppose $p|[G:P]$, then there exists $1\le k'$ such that $[G:P]=p^{k'}m'$ for some $m'$ with $gcd(p,m')=1$. Therefore $|G|=m'p^{k+k'}$. Since $k+k'>k,$ by first Sylow Theorem,there exists a $p$-subgroup $P'$ with $|P'|=P^{k+1}$. By Second Sylow Theorem, we have $P<aP'a^{-1}$ for some $a\in G$, which implies $p^k=|P|\le |aP'a^{-1}|=|P'|=p^{k+1}$. Contradiction.

Comment: The  first definition is more general. The second definition only makes sense if the index $[G:P]$ is finite.

Comment: Thank you @DerekHolt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go differently:

You may want to use the "maximal hypothesis". Take the first definition you have given. Therefore $p^k$ is the maximal power of the prime $p$ dividing the order of $G$. Then by Lagrange's you know that $|G|=mp^k$ and of course $m$ is not divisible by $p$ since otherwise, by Sylow Theorem, there would be a subgroup of order $p^{k+1}$ , which violates the hypothesis of maximality. On the other hand, if you take the second definition, if there is a subgroup of order $p^k$ and $p$ does not divide $m$, by Lagrange's it is automatically maximal and therefore the two definitions coincide.

Comment: why $p^k$  is the maximal power of the prime $p$ dividing the order of $G$? Is it possible there is a $p$-group $P'$ with larger order than $P$ but not containing $P$?

Comment: Well, if there were such a group that would be another Sylow p-subgroup, but all Sylow p-subgroup are isomorphic via conjugation, in particular they must have same order, so this would be a violation. It would be another Sylow p-subgroup because by Langrange's every of its subgroups (in particular cyclic subgroups) would be a power of $p$, since the order of the subgroup is a power of $p$, and thus the order of every element would be a power of $p$. Moreover it cannot be contained by any subgroup of lower order and therefore it is a Sylow p-subgroup. Hope this was clear!

Comment: Of course if you suppose again there is another, bigger $p$-subgroup then we could make this reasoning again, so it's worth assuming that this, eventual, $p$-subgroup is of order the maximal power of $p$, then we repeat the aforementioned reasoning and we show that $k$ must be the maximal power.

Comment: Thank you. @Bellem